# How to find parent nodes path from flattened array?

Tags: javascript

I have flattened hierarchy array as follows.
I'd like to get path to the specific node as array.

```
var arr = [

    {id:1, parent_id:null},
    {id:2, parent_id:1},
    {id:3, parent_id:null},
    {id:4, parent_id:2},
    {id:5, parent_id:4}

]

getPath(arr, 5) return [1,2,4]
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried to write this function yourself? What kind of suggestion do you need? You haven’t shown any attempt.

Comment: I'm sorry, I could not resolve this problem, and more I'm not native english so that I could not explain my thought.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a hash table for all `id` and their parents and iterate until no parent is available.

```js
function getPath(nodes, id) {
    var parents = Object.create(null),
        path = [];

    nodes.forEach(function (n) {
        parents[n.id] = n.parent_id;
    });

    while (id = parents[id]) {
        path.unshift(id);
    }
    return path;
}

var array = [{ id: 1, parent_id: null }, { id: 2, parent_id: 1 }, { id: 3, parent_id: null }, { id: 4, parent_id: 2 }, { id: 5, parent_id: 4 }];

console.log(getPath(array, 5)); // [1, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a recursive function that finds the item in the array with an `id` value matching the provided `key` parameter, and then checks if the current item has a `parent_id` truthy value.

**If there is a `parent_id`:**

The function will define `results` as an array if it wasn't passed into the function, and will then add the current item's `parent_id` to the front of the `results` array. Next, it will call itself with the following three parameters:

1. The starting array (`arr`).
2. The current item's `parent_id` as the `key` to look at next.
3. The `results` array as the array to return when completely done.

**If there is no `parent_id`:**

The function will instead return the `results` array.

```js
var arr = [
{id:1, parent_id:null},
{id:2, parent_id:1},
{id:3, parent_id:null},
{id:4, parent_id:2},
{id:5, parent_id:4}
];

function getPath(arr, key, results) {
    var nextObj = arr.filter(function(obj){
        return obj.id == key;
    })[0];
    if(nextObj && nextObj.parent_id) {
        results = typeof results !== 'object' ? [] : results;
        var nextKey = nextObj.parent_id;
        results.unshift(nextKey);
        return getPath(arr, nextKey, results);
    }
    return results;
}

console.log(getPath(arr, 5));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my simple answer for what you want to achieve:

```js
var arr = [

    {id:1, parent_id:null},
    {id:2, parent_id:1},
    {id:3, parent_id:null},
    {id:4, parent_id:2},
    {id:5, parent_id:4}
];
var res=[];
function getPath(arr, x){
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i].id== x){
            getPath(arr, arr[i].parent_id);
            if(arr[i].parent_id !== null){
           res.push(arr[i].parent_id);
            }
            

        }
    }

}
getPath(arr, 5);
console.log(res);
```

I have just used recursion and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

Recursive function to get the desired output.

```js
var arr = [

    {id:1, parent_id:null},
    {id:2, parent_id:1},
    {id:3, parent_id:null},
    {id:4, parent_id:2},
    {id:5, parent_id:4}

]

let resultArr = [];

function getPath(arr, num) {
 for(var i in arr) {
   if(arr[i].id === num) {
     //console.log(num);
      getPath(arr, arr[i].parent_id);
      resultArr.push(num);
   break;
    }
  }
  
  return resultArr.slice(0, (resultArr.length - 1));
}

var res = getPath(arr, 5);
console.log(res);
```